# How can I write SQL statements for psycopg2 for PostreSQL and sqlite3?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite

I use the psycopg2 library for PostgreSQL in python for my production environment but I want to test my code with the sqlite3 library. The problem is that psycopg2 uses `%s` as a placeholder for parameter substitution, whereas sqlite3 uses `?`.

I am not happy with the code I got now, it looks like this:

```
queries = {
     'is_admin':          "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE user_id = ?;",
}

if dbtype == 'postgres':
    for key, value in queries.items():
        queries[key] = value.replace('?', '%s')
```

It's kind of an ugly hack but I don't want to write all my queries two times, so what's the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Your hack also runs the risk of replacing legitimate '?' in a query should they exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using simple `?` to `%s` string replacement is dangerous, you may break your query, or harm the actual data in all sorts of unpredictable ways which could be difficult to debug.

---

Look into the "SQL for humans" [`records` package](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records) that provides a uniform parameterization style for all the supported databases.

Note that `records` achieves the database-agnostic parameterization style only because of using the [`text()` function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) from the `SQLAlchemy` package. You may as well use it directly:

> The advantages `text()` provides over a plain string are backend-neutral
>   support for bind parameters, per-statement execution options, as well
>   as bind parameter and result-column typing behavior, allowing
>   SQLAlchemy type constructs to play a role when executing a statement
>   that is specified literally.